Inverse image of closure under perfect open mapping.
Let $f$ be an open and perfect mapping from $X$ to $Y$. Let $A \subset Y$ and let $y \in \overline{A}$, then whether it is true that $f^{-1}(y) \subset \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$.
I have assumed that $y \in \overline{A} \setminus A$. Let $x = f^{-1}(y)$ i.e. $f(x) = y$. Let $U$ be any open set containing $x$, then I need to show that $U$ intersects with ${f^{-1}(A)}$.
Now $f(x) \in f(U)$ which implies that $f(U) \cap A \neq \emptyset$
i.e. $f^{-1}(f(U) \cap A) \neq \emptyset$
i.e. $f^{-1}(f(U)) \cap f^{-1}(A) \neq \emptyset$.
But this doesn't imply that $U$ intersects with $f^{-1}(A).$
Am I missing some concept to get the required result?
Please clarify on this.

If f is open, then $f^{-1}(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$ for each subset $A$ of $Y$. No perfectness needed, not even continuity.

In your above proof, just consider $u \in U$ such that $f(u) \in A$.

Thanks Ulli. I need to ask one more thing whether the inverse image of compact sets is compact under open maps.

No, of course not: $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow {0}$.

Can you give any example of a bijective mapping??

Before you ask again and again, what is your definition of open map? And what is your final question?

Is it true that the inverse image of compact is compact under bijective open maps????

Yes, of course: the inverse map of an open, bijective map is continuous. This holds for both possible definitions of openness, which you still haven't specified.
